# Can we declare a function with the same signature but different return type in the base class?

Tags: c++

the question may look silly ,but i want to ask..
         Is there any way we can declare a method in a class with same signature but different return type (like int fun(int) and float fun(int) ) and during the object creation can we dynamically decide which function to be executed! i have got the compilation error...is there any other way to achieve this logic may be using templates...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always take the return value as a template.

```
template<typename T> T fun(int);
template<> float fun<float>(int);
template<> int fun<int>(int);
```

Can you decide dynamically at run-time which to call? No.

Answer (score 0):

@DeadMG proposed the template based solution, however you can simply "tweak" the signature (which is, arguably, what the template argument does).

The idea is simply to add a dummy argument:

```
struct Foo
{
  float fun(float); // no name, it's a dummy
  int fun(int);     // no name, it's a dummy
};
```

Then for execution:

```
int main() {
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.fun(int()) << ", " << foo.fun(float());
}
```

This can be used exactly as the template solution (ie invoked from a template method), but is much easier to pull:

- less wordy
- function template specialization should be defined outside the class (although VC++ will accept inline definition in the class)

I prefer to avoid function template specialization, in general, as with specialization on arguments, the rules for selecting the right overload/specialization are tricky.

Comment: ya..this is a direct example of function overloading ri8..because the arguments are of different type to the same function in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can (but shouldn't<sup>*</sup>) use a proxy class that overloads the conversion operators.

## Long example with actual usecase <sup>*</sup>

Let me take my example from [Dot & Cross Product Notation](http://ompf.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1453):

[...]

There is also the possibility of having operator* for both dot-product and cross-product.

Assume a basic vector-type (just for demonstration):

```
struct Vector {  
         float x,y,z;  
         Vector() {}  
         Vector (float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}  
};
```

We observe that the dot-product is a scalar, the cross-product is a vector. In C++, we may overload conversion operators:

```
struct VecMulRet {
public:
        operator Vector ()  const {
                return Vector (
                        lhs.y*rhs.z - lhs.z*rhs.y,
                        lhs.z*rhs.x - lhs.x*rhs.z,
                        lhs.x*rhs.y - lhs.y*rhs.x
                );
        }
        operator float () const {
                return lhs.x*rhs.x + lhs.y*rhs.y + lhs.z*rhs.z;
        }
private:
        // make construction private and only allow operator* to create an instance
        Vector const lhs, rhs;

        VecMulRet (Vector const &lhs, Vector const &rhs)
        : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs)
        {}

        friend VecMulRet operator * (Vector const &lhs, Vector const &rhs);
};
```

Only operator* is allowed to use struct VecMulRet, copying of VecMulRet is forbidden (paranoia first).

Operator* is now defined as follows:

```
VecMulRet operator * (Vector const &lhs, Vector const &rhs) {
        return VecMulRet (lhs, rhs);
}
```

Et voila, we can write:

```
int main () {
        Vector a,b;
        float dot = a*b;
        Vector cross = a*b;
}
```

Btw, this is blessed by the Holy Standard as established in 1999.

If you read further in that thread, you'll find a benchmark that confirms that this comes at no performance penalty.

## Short example for demonstration <sup>*</sup>

If that was too much to grasp, a more constructed example:

```
struct my_multi_ret {
    operator unsigned int() const { return 0xdeadbeef; }
    operator float()        const { return 42.f;       } 
};

my_multi_ret multi () {
    return my_multi_ret();
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main () {
    unsigned int i = multi();
    float f = multi();
    std::cout << std::hex << i << ", " << f << std::endl;
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> You can, but shouldn't, because it does not conform to the principle of least surprise as it is not common practice. Still, it is funny.